# Loop within dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This is the dictionary I am referring to:

```
members = {
    1: {"name": "Farly Waller", "country": "Russia", "following": [11, 18, 17, 20]},
    2: {"name": "Jania Hardistry", "country": "Indonesia", "following": [3, 8, 15, 20]},
    3: {"name": "Yale Shortan", "country": "Brazil", "following": [2, 4, 8]},
    4: {"name": "Redford Melloi", "country": "Philippines", "following": [1, 3, 13, 14]},
    5: {"name": "Lisbeth Cello", "country": "Pakistan", "following": [4, 7, 10]},
    6: {"name": "Andrew Flaonier", "country": "Pakistan", "following": []},
    7: {"name": "Pris Pilmore", "country": "Japan", "following": [5, 6, 9, 1, 15, 16]},
    8: {"name": "Starla Buffey", "country": "Colombia", "following": [10, 2, 3]},
    9: {"name": "Clark Goymer", "country": "Thailand", "following": [7, 11]},
    10: {"name": "Gayle Testin", "country": "Brazil", "following": [8, 5, 15, 19, 13]},
    11: {"name": "Serena Brombell", "country": "China", "following": [1, 17, 18]},
    12: {"name": "Wendy Toke", "country": "Peru", "following": []},
    13: {"name": "Clarice Shelmardine", "country": "Portugal", "following": [10, 1, 14, 15, 16, 19]},
    14: {"name": "Julie Corradeschi", "country": "Peru", "following": [13, 1, 2, 4]},
    15: {"name": "Constantin Sebire", "country": "China", "following": [3, 10, 13, 16, 18]},
    16: {"name": "Annadiane Mum", "country": "Japan", "following": [7, 13, 6, 18]},
    17: {"name": "Lovell Lubbock", "country": "China", "following": [1, 11, 20]},
    18: {"name": "Gwynne Toplis", "country": "China", "following": [1, 11, 16, 17]},
    19: {"name": "Pammy Urey", "country": "Yemen", "following": [10, 6, 13, 20]},
    20: {"name": "Celestina Phillipps", "country": "Canada", "following": [3, 17]},
```

I am struggling with this code:

```
    followers = {}
for user_id in members:
    followers[user_id]=[]
    for user1 in members[user_id]["following"]:
        if user1 in members[user_id]["following"]: 
            
            followers[user_id].append(user1)
        
print(followers)
```

currently for each user_id the people this person follows are displayed, but I actually want to see from each person the followers, so e.g.,
For user 5, the value should be the list `[7, 10].`
For user 1, the value should be the list `[4, 7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18]`.

Does anyone know how to make the switch?

Best, Emma

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invert keys and values of the original dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304980/invert-keys-and-values-of-the-original-dictionary)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inverting a dictionary with lists as values (which must not repeat as keys)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69598254/inverting-a-dictionary-with-lists-as-values-which-must-not-repeat-as-keys)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,

```
d = {}
for k, v in members.items():
    for i in v.get('following'):
        d.setdefault(i, []).append(k)
```

Output:

```
{11: [1, 9, 17, 18],
 18: [1, 11, 15, 16],
 17: [1, 11, 18, 20],
 20: [1, 2, 17, 19],
 3: [2, 4, 8, 15, 20],
 8: [2, 3, 10],
 15: [2, 7, 10, 13],
 2: [3, 8, 14],
 4: [3, 5, 14],
 1: [4, 7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18],
 13: [4, 10, 14, 15, 16, 19],
 14: [4, 13],
 7: [5, 9, 16],
 10: [5, 8, 13, 15, 19],
 5: [7, 10],
 6: [7, 16, 19],
 9: [7],
 16: [7, 13, 15, 18],
 19: [10, 13]}
```

Comment: you can save a couple of lines with `d.setdefault(i, []).append(k)` or `defaultdict`

Comment: @gog That's an impressive tip. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this :

```
followers = {}

for person in members.keys():
    person_followers = []
    for user, detail in members.items():
        if person != user and person in detail["following"]:
            person_followers.append(user)
    followers[person] = person_followers

followers
```

Result :

```
{1: [4, 7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18],
 2: [3, 8, 14],
 3: [2, 4, 8, 15, 20],
 4: [3, 5, 14],
 5: [7, 10],
 6: [7, 16, 19],
 7: [5, 9, 16],
 8: [2, 3, 10], ... }
```

Comment: You loop over the entire dictionary as many times as there are items in it, but only one loop is necessary. Best use collections.defaultdict(list) for collecting the ids of followers and get rid of the loop `for person in members.keys():`.

Comment: See the other answer for how it can be done.